# jquery select item by contains 1.10.2

Tags: jquery

This work with jquery 1.4.4, but i need same for 1.10.2, Thanks for any reply!

```
<select id="region_id" name="region_id" class="control-self control-self-select m_js_region">
    <option>Chose region</option>
    <option>Moscow</option>
    <option>Saint-Petersburg</option>
</select>
$("#region_id :contains('Moscow')").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$("#region_id :contains('Moscow')").prop("selected", "selected");
```

Comment: it is recommended to use a boolean instead

Answer (score 1):

Use `prop()` instead:

```
$("#region_id :contains('Moscow')").prop("selected", true);
```